# FQL - App request table

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using app request table to get the invite sender uid but i'm getting an empty array as an result.

```
  // Run fql query
      $params = array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => "SELECT request_id, app_id, recipient_uid, sender_uid FROM apprequest   
      WHERE app_id = 234234324324324 and request_id =".$request_id,
    );

    $result = $facebook->api($params);
```

Comment: Tried including your access_token?

Comment: OptimusCrime:Where to add it access_tokn and how do i get that access token

Comment: You don't need to handle the access_token if you're using the PHP SDK and the $facebook->api(); method

Comment: Did you do this before or after authorizing the app?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer to your problem.  On the documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/apprequest/), in the table of columns, it states the following:

`app_id: The ID of the app used to send the request. Note when indexing by app_id, you must also specify the recipient_uid.`

**-- AND --**

`recipient_uid: The ID of the user who received the request. Note when indexing by recipient_uid, you must also specify the app_id.`

**When I tried to execute your query, I received the following error:**

```
"message": "(#604) Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ",
```

**Your query is currently:**

`SELECT request_id, app_id, recipient_uid, sender_uid FROM apprequest WHERE app_id = 234234324324324 and request_id =".$request_id`

You'll notice that you're not following these rules, as you've specified 'app_id' in your WHERE clause but with no 'recipient_uid'.

Try doing your query without your app_id specified.

Comment: :I want the invite sender uid

Comment: Say i'm a ,send request to b.i need a uid.where is that access_token in facebook

Comment: @user1010611 apologies, I got the wrong end of the stick.  Please see my revised answer

Comment: Please see this revised answer

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
void FacebookManager::GetRequests()
{
    FBRequest *fql = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"fql"];
    [fql.parameters setObject:@"SELECT request_id, app_id, recipient_uid FROM apprequest WHERE app_id = <your app id> AND recipient_uid = <your fbid>"
                       forKey:@"q"];

    FBRequestConnection* rc = [fql startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
        if (result) {
            NSLog(@"result:%@", result);
        }
    }];
}
```

This gives me a json array written to the debug output window.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Run fql query 
$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query', 
    'query' => "SELECT request_id, app_id, recipient_uid, sender_uid FROM apprequest WHERE app_id = 234234324324324 and request_id =".$request_id,
    'access_token' => $yourAccessTokenVar);
```

I assume you have your access_token-code in a variabel (you need this to get the app running), just replace `$yourAccessTokenVar` with this variable.

EDIT: By the way, you had a comma too much in your array.

Comment: Because the user is using the Facebook PHP SDK, this is handled automatically I believe

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code. Mind posting the part of the code where you use new Facebook(); in your script? Post it at http://pastebin.com/ or something (don't forget to censor your private information)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, it's the Authentication-part I need ;)

Comment: You don't need to handle the access_token if you're using the PHP SDK and the $facebook->api(); method.  It is handled automatically by the SDK.

Comment: You're still not including the part with the access_token. Not sure where you have that. I can check an example with the php sdk. Have you made sure your query does return something? Try using the sandbox

Comment: @OptimusCrime:Post a link which has access token

Comment: If FQL is returning no error, there is no exception, then your access_token is fine.  Have you tried running the query from https://graph.facebook.com and checked the response from the graph for your query?  `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20request_id... FROM &access_token=...`

Comment: @Coulton:I see many links at that page.Which do you want me to click and what will i get to know from it?